# Merge Records Over Time Interval

Tags: r, time, intervals

Let me begin by saying this question pertains to R (stat programming language) but I'm open straightforward suggestions for other environments.

The goal is to merge outcomes from dataframe (df) A to sub-elements in df B. This is a one to many relationship but, here's **the twist**, once the records are matched by keys they also have to match over a specific frame of time given by a start time and duration.

For example, a few records in df A:

```
    OBS ID StartTime Duration Outcome 
    1   01 10:12:06  00:00:10 Normal
    2   02 10:12:30  00:00:30 Weird
    3   01 10:15:12  00:01:15 Normal
    4   02 10:45:00  00:00:02 Normal
```

And from df B:

```
    OBS ID Time       
    1   01 10:12:10  
    2   01 10:12:17  
    3   02 10:12:45  
    4   01 10:13:00
```

The desired outcome from the merge would be:

```
    OBS ID Time     Outcome  
    1   01 10:12:10 Normal 
    3   02 10:12:45 Weird
```

Desired result: dataframe B with outcomes merged in from A. Notice observations 2 and 4 were dropped because although they matched IDs on records in A they did not fall within any of the time intervals given.

**Question**

Is it possible to perform this sort of operation in R and how would you get started? If not, can you suggest an alternative tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Set up data**

First set up the input data frames.  We create two versions of the data frames:  `A` and `B` just use character columns for the times and `At` and `Bt` use the chron package `"times"` class for the times (which has the advantage over `"character"` class that one can add and subtract them):

```
LinesA <- "OBS ID StartTime Duration Outcome 
    1   01 10:12:06  00:00:10 Normal
    2   02 10:12:30  00:00:30 Weird
    3   01 10:15:12  00:01:15 Normal
    4   02 10:45:00  00:00:02 Normal"

LinesB <- "OBS ID Time       
    1   01 10:12:10  
    2   01 10:12:17  
    3   02 10:12:45  
    4   01 10:13:00"

A <- At <- read.table(textConnection(LinesA), header = TRUE, 
               colClasses = c("numeric", rep("character", 4)))
B <- Bt <- read.table(textConnection(LinesB), header = TRUE, 
               colClasses = c("numeric", rep("character", 2)))

# in At and Bt convert times columns to "times" class

library(chron) 

At$StartTime <- times(At$StartTime)
At$Duration <- times(At$Duration)
Bt$Time <- times(Bt$Time)
```

**sqldf with times class**

Now we can perform the calculation using the [sqldf](http://sqldf.googlecode.com) package.  We use `method="raw"` (which does not assign classes to the output) so we must assign the `"times"` class to the output `"Time"` column ourself:

```
library(sqldf)

out <- sqldf("select Bt.OBS, ID, Time, Outcome from At join Bt using(ID)
   where Time between StartTime and StartTime + Duration",
   method = "raw")

out$Time <- times(as.numeric(out$Time))
```

The result is:

```
> out
      OBS ID     Time Outcome
1   1 01 10:12:10  Normal
2   3 02 10:12:45   Weird
```

With the development version of sqldf this can be done without using `method="raw"` and the `"Time"` column will automatically be set to `"times"` class by the sqldf class assignment heuristic:

```
library(sqldf)
source("http://sqldf.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/R/sqldf.R") # grab devel ver 
sqldf("select Bt.OBS, ID, Time, Outcome from At join Bt using(ID)
    where Time between StartTime and StartTime + Duration")
```

**sqldf with character class**

Its actually possible to *not* use the `"times"` class by performing all time calculations in sqlite out of character strings employing sqlite's [strftime](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) function.  The SQL statement is unfortunately a bit more involved:

```
sqldf("select B.OBS, ID, Time, Outcome from A join B using(ID)
    where strftime('%s', Time) - strftime('%s', StartTime)
       between 0 and strftime('%s', Duration) - strftime('%s', '00:00:00')")
```

EDIT:

A series of edits which fixed grammar, added additional approaches and fixed/improved the `read.table` statements.

EDIT:

Simplified/improved final sqldf statement.

Answer (score 2):

here is an example:

```
# first, merge by ID
z <- merge(A[, -1], B, by = "ID")

# convert string to POSIX time
z <- transform(z,
  s_t = as.numeric(strptime(as.character(z$StartTime), "%H:%M:%S")),
  dur = as.numeric(strptime(as.character(z$Duration), "%H:%M:%S")) - 
    as.numeric(strptime("00:00:00", "%H:%M:%S")),
  tim = as.numeric(strptime(as.character(z$Time), "%H:%M:%S")))

# subset by time range
subset(z, s_t < tim & tim < s_t + dur)
```

the output:

```
  ID StartTime Duration Outcome OBS     Time        s_t dur        tim
1  1  10:12:06 00:00:10  Normal   1 10:12:10 1321665126  10 1321665130
2  1  10:12:06 00:00:10  Normal   2 10:12:15 1321665126  10 1321665135
7  2  10:12:30 00:00:30   Weird   3 10:12:45 1321665150  30 1321665165
```

OBS #2 looks to be in the range. does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Merge the two data.frames together with `merge()`. Then `subset()` the resulting data.frame with the condition `time >= startTime & time <= startTime + Duration` or whatever rules make sense to you.