# Merge dataframes in R by condition

Tags: r

I want to merge a dataframe that contains the attributes "startAltitude" and "endAltitude" with another dataframe that contains "Altitude" and merge it such that Altitude lies in this interval. How do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post a minimal working example showing what you've tried so far. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185201/merge-records-over-time-interval

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42507882/merge-two-dataframes-if-timestamp-of-x-is-within-time-interval-of-y